# sort the index of multiindex dataframe which contains both text and string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting, multi-index

I have a Multi Index dataframe so I want to sort it based on ID2 which contains both text and number.
I am using Python 3.7

```
MultiIndex([(1, 'HK_MN001'),
            (2, 'HK_MN001'),
            (3, 'HK_MN002'),
            (4, 'HK_MN003'),
            (5, 'HK_MN004'),
            (6, 'HK_MN005'),
            (7, 'HK_MN005'),
            (8, 'HK_MN005')],
           names=['ID1', 'ID2'])
```

I tried this code but gives me error:

```
a = final_df1.index.get_level_values(1).to_series().str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).sort_values()

final_df1 = final_df1.reindex(index=a.index)
```

Error:

```
final_df1 = final_df1.reindex(index=a.index)  # error at this line
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
```

Comment: There is always `HK_MN` in second level? How working `df = df.sort_index(level=1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use if need sorting by number in second level removing convert level to `Series`, remove `sort_values` and add [`Index.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html) for positions of sorted values, so change ordering get pass to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 'HK_MN001'),
            (2, 'HK_MN001'),
            (3, 'HK_MN002'),
            (4, 'HK_MN003'),
            (5, 'HK_MN004'),
            (6, 'HK_MN005'),
            (7, 'HK_MN005'),
            (8, 'HK_MN005')],
           names=['ID1', 'ID2'])

final_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(8)}, index=mux)
print (final_df1)
              a
ID1 ID2        
1   HK_MN001  0
2   HK_MN001  1
3   HK_MN002  2
4   HK_MN003  3
5   HK_MN004  4
6   HK_MN005  5
7   HK_MN005  6
8   HK_MN005  7
```

---

```
a = final_df1.index.get_level_values(1).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
print (a)
Int64Index([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5], dtype='int64', name='ID2')

df = final_df1.iloc[a.argsort()]
print (df)
              a
ID1 ID2        
1   HK_MN001  0
2   HK_MN001  1
3   HK_MN002  2
4   HK_MN003  3
5   HK_MN004  4
6   HK_MN005  5
7   HK_MN005  6
8   HK_MN005  7
```

But if possible, simplier is use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), if possible sorting by text and number together:

```
df = final_df1.sort_index(level=1)
```